# Electron | how to enable autocomplete for simple html text input?

Tags: autocomplete, electron

electron version: 28.1.3

I have an electron app, and I wish the application to save history of user emails, but for some reason even if I do

```
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="email">
```

it doesn't enable the feature, that as much as it hard to believe I suspect that it doesn't exists on electron.

any ideas?